# Postman get request with multiple queryparams with the same key returns empty list

Tags: java, postman, query-string

I am trying to get a list value of all of my product which corresponds to my research criteria, in my case research criteria are their references and their region by using Postman (GET METHOD):

```
https://localhost/services/choices/?ref=test1&ref=test2&region=west
```

But whenever I try to get my references in my code, I receive a list with zero size.

```
@Path("/choices")
@GET
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@ApiOperation(value = "get products")
@ApiResponses(value = {@ApiResponse(code=200,message = "Success"),
        @ApiResponse(code=500, message = "Server error")
})
public Response getProduct(@QueryParam("ref") final List<String> ref,
                           @QueryParam("region") final String region,
                          @Context final HttpServletRequest request){
    LOGGER.info("Call for references {} and region {}",ref,region);
    try{


        return Response.ok(productBusinessService.getProducts(ref,region)).build();

    }catch (Exception e){

        throw new InternalServerErrorHttpException("Technical Error", e.getMessage(), e);
    }finally {
        LOGGER.info("End of the Call for references {} and region {}",ref,region);
    }
}
```

My question is : Is it possible to pass multiple query parameters with the same key name in postman,if yes why do I receive empty list while I get the value of region

Comment: what happens if you try to reach the api with curl?

Comment: I don't think this is problem of postman. I've made exact same service and its works with multi parameter

Answer (score 0):

Actually, I had to restart my postman client for it to work, so restarting the client can be as solution